# very tiny shopping cart images

Tags: magento2

I don't think I've touched this part but the cart images are showing extremely tiny images

This is the one where you click on the shopping cart. I'm extending form the Luma theme

[image]

this is when I inspect element from the image shows rendered size 8x8

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a css problem to me. You can right click on picture and open it in a tab to see the real size.

In any case, the size of the product images can be controlled via the file view.xml

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/themes/configure/

You can copy the file from the luma/blank theme and paste on your theme path  <theme_dir>/etc/view.xml

Comment: I made an edit to my post

Comment: As you can see the real size of the picture is 75x75, so there is a css/layout problem. 
It's not possible fix your problem with this information. You can try to force the image at a witdh of 75px with a css rule